# Сервис всевозможных опросов

Tags: предложение, статус-отклонено

Может это уже и есть, а я просто не знаю.

<s>Если так, то можно спокойно закрыть тему, тыкнув носом куда смотреть.</s>

Хотелось бы, чтобы на SO был сервис всевозможных опросов аля:

- Какой ОС вы пользуетесь дома/на_работе?
- Какой IDE вы пользуетесь дома/на_работе?
- Каким фреймворком вы пользуетесь дома/на_работе?
- Ваш любимый язык программирования?
- ...?

Опросы можно сделать бессрочными, то есть они никогда не заканчиваются; при этом пользователь может изменить свой ответ с течением времени.

Можно ограничить рейтинг, необходимый для участия в опросе, чтобы добавить строгости.

Можно сделать возможность добавлять свои опросы.

<s>Все же любили анкетки в школе.</s>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подобные вопросы не несут никакой пользы сообществу, но вред от них очевиден – огромное количество ненужного информационного шума, который будет лишь отвлекать от действительно полезных действий. На основном сайте подобной функции не будет, она противоречит идеологии проекта.

Если вы хотите поднять подобный вопрос в сообществе, пожалуйста, воспользуйтесь Метой, если результат дискуссии может быть полезен кому-либо, помимо участников диалога, или чатом, во всех остальных случаях.

Answer (score 7):

Это развлекательная возможность, которая не решает основную задачу Stack Overflow на русском и всех остальных сайтов сети SE - накопление и обмен знаниями, решениями, идеями.

Однако раз в год проводится большой опрос Stack Overflow Developer Survey, в котором есть некоторые из предложенных вами вопросов.

Comment: [Результаты опроса в 2016 году](http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016)

Comment: С одной стороны я с вами согласен насчёт развлекательности ... Но если посмотреть с другой стороны: провели опрос раз в год и кто-то зашёл посмотреть результаты через 6 месяцев — вы сами понимаете, что результаты уже неактуальны — я бы даже сказал — они актульны максимум месяц ... А развлекательности можно поубавить если не делать возможность создавать свои вопросы, например, + рейтинг для участия минимум 20 кусов .... Также, можно сказать, что результаты этих опросов — это как бы и есть `обмен знаниями` — опытные разработчики деляться своим опытом, учавствую в таком опросе.